# Add geometric circles to uploaded picture

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I would like to upload an image/picture to a website and in a preview i would like to add or draw a red circle on the top of the image and save it as a new photo.

How is this archiveable? I have added an image as an example.

[image: Red circle on top of image]

Any known scripts or similar, which could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "***Canvas***": 
in HTML to dynamically apply the circle. (it will not modify the image)

Look the snippet here : (the **yellow circle** is the one)

1. use x,y to position the circle on img...
2. use radius to set the size of circle
3. color the color... stroke the thickness...

```js
function drowCircle(canvas, x, y, radius, color, stroke){
    canvas.width = (radius+stroke)*2;
    canvas.height = (radius+stroke)*2;
    canvas.style.top = y+"px";
    canvas.style.left = x+"px";
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc((canvas.width/2),(canvas.height/2),radius,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    context.lineWidth=stroke;
    context.strokeStyle=color;
    context.stroke();
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    drowCircle(document.getElementById("mycanvas"), 100, 200, 25, "yellow", 5);
},false)
```

```css
#mycanvas{
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer" style="position:relative;">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoRrD.jpg" alt="" />
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Note that canvas is only supported by modern browsers....

To all into a single image you need two images (the circle, and the picture)
and you can do it only server-side (php):

Search stackoverflow for "**php watermark**"

a video guide on youtube : [php watermark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFSkPzJNAho)

Comment: Looks cool. But i want the user to be able to like drag and drop the location of the watermark. And then when they're done, save the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: to move the image you should make the canvas draggable. To save it as a single image you need to do it server-side (like PHP) I post some links...

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php): you can add a watermark.

> Note: You need to enable
>   *extension*=**php_gd2**

PHP

```
// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
    <div class="watermark"></div>
</div>

<a id="getPos" href="javascript: void(0);">Get Position</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $(".watermark").each(function () {
        $(this).draggable({
            containment: $(this).parent(".image")
        });
    });

    $("#getPos").click(function(){
        var imgPos = $(".image img").offset();
        var wmPos_tmp = $(".watermark").offset();

        var watermarkPosition = {
            top: wmPos_tmp.top - imgPos.top,
            left: wmPos_tmp.left - imgPos.left
        }
        console.log(watermarkPosition);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}
.watermark {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 140px;
}
```

Comment: But the location of the circle should manually be specified straight after upload? Is that possible with watermark?

Comment: In this case the watermark is another image that will be placed on top of the original image, and both will form one image. Location of the watermark will be placed in the example with $marge_ right and bottom, as a fixed position.

Comment: Okay, i need for the user to be able to move et around dynamically. :/

Comment: In this case you need to handle the watermark image with a JavaScript script to get the desired position.

Comment: i added a javascript example: how to get position before forming the final image.